# Cloud Firestore says Code 14 Unavailable in all request PHP

Tags: php, laravel, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm starting a project with Laravel 6.2, added [kreait/laravel-firebase](https://github.com/kreait/laravel-firebase) and configured it with the .json configuration file to work with Realtime database and works like a charm.

Later I read that Cloud Firestore is better. So I've installed the library [google cloud](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-php) and use the example provided:

```
    public function test(){
    $db = new FirestoreClient();
    $docRef = $db->collection('users')->document('aturing');
    $docRef->set([
        'first' => 'Alan',
        'middle' => 'Mathison',
        'last' => 'Turing',
        'born' => 1912
    ]);
    printf('Added data to the aturing document in the users collection.' . PHP_EOL);

}
```

That request and every request throws me  this exception:

> Google\Cloud\Core\Exception\ServiceException
>   { "message": "Empty update", "code": 14, "status": "UNAVAILABLE", "details": [] }

[image]

I searched the docs, forums, everything and I can't find an answer.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you set up the environment variable `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` pointing to your service account file somewhere, probably in the .env file? Your code doesn‘t show if/where you do this. You can find more details in the authentication section in the readme of the google/cloud package.

Comment: BTW, in the case of the Firestore Client, the Laravel Package/Firebase Admin SDK is just a wrapper around the FirestoreClient with some convenience added around Facades/Dependency injection. If you‘re only using Firestore, just using the google package is totally enough - if you want to use other components of the Firebase package, I‘d still recommend the kreait SDK (of course, because disclaimer: I‘m the maintainer ^^)

Comment: Hi @jeromegamez, thanks for your response. First of all, thanks for such a great lib, you're doing a great job! :D.

About the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS  I forgot to mention it. I added to the system env, also I renamed it, so the lib couldn't find it and it throws me a different error. Also, I debugged the Firestore object and it has the projectId inside and other configs, so the json config is read correctly.

Also, I tried to get the Cloud Firestore from the $factory->createFirestore(); of the Kreait library and I have the same error.

Comment: Hmmm... I wonder if the Firebase APIs might have been down without https://status.cloud.google.com/ or https://status.firebase.google.com/ showing it. I've looked a bit into the error code and it looks like this error occurs when the service is in fact unavailable. It could also be a docker networking issue (I noticed you're using Laragon), or a networking issue from your local environment to the Google APIs. Have you tried running the call elsewhere, e.g. from a remote server?

Comment: Oh, let me take a look at that point. Thank you!

Comment: I just encountered this error as well while working on the SDK (after updating PHP and the PECL extension). These GitHub issues seem to be related: https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-php/issues/2427, https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/21556, https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/21535 and others (linked within those issues). Downgrading the extension to 1.25.0 with `pecl install grpc-1.25.0` didn't solve the issue for me, but I hope it does for you ^^

Comment: Hey @jeromegamez, I downgraded the extension and didn't work. I'm trying to get a remote server to test it out. Also, I'll run a Homestead VM to try it out. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @jeromegamez check https://stackoverflow.com/a/59630501/3200714 now it's working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue in Laravel, the solution is to pin in composer.json grpc/grpc to version 1.19 and then restart apache.

```
"require": {
   "grpc/grpc": "1.19"
}
```

More details here: https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-php/issues/2539

Answer (score 1):

I got same issue on my local in project laravel with xampp php 7.4 and grpc 1.26 but on my remote server working fine with same version grpc